# How can I prevent chrome from remember its last location?

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome

When I run Chrome , it remembers its last position

As you can see here :

[image: http://i.imgur.com/x2sVGiL.gif]

(also , if I start a new 100x100 chrome instance , the next time I invoke a new chrome , it is opened same size , near it - I don't want that)

**Question :**

Is there any setting/switch for chrome to not remember its last location ?

NB

I'm looking for a solution without using extension